# IBM.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0 client instance of DbContext in a class library goes to null after first query

Tags: entity-framework-core, db2, .net-6.0

an issue with the DB2 Entity Framework Core 6.0 DbContext inside a C# class library has made a spaghetti brain out of me.

This same code works when DbcProd context and Model folder are inside the client project, but when they're used from a class library, the client app errors with "Specified cast is not valid".

I emphasize that exact same DbcProd class and Model folders are copied to class library, only fixup is the namespace change.

The context is generated from runing Scaffold-DbContext with the client startup project.

```
var contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbcProd>()
    .UseDb2("server=xxxx:xxxx;database=xxxx;uid=xxxx;pwd=xxxx;", x => x.SetServerInfo(IBMDBServerType.LUW))
    .Options;
var dbContext = new DbcProd(contextOptions); // dbContext variable has instance of DbcProd

// after this query, the dbContext variable is null, there is also a "Specified cast is not valid" exception on this line
// but when DbcProd is instantiated from local Model folder inside this client project, no error occurs
var option = dbcontext.OPTIONS.Find(1); 

Console.WriteLine(option.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the NET 6.0 Nullable Reference Types, which adds this line to all the projects by default: `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in the .csproj file.

The solution (for now) is to comment-out that element `<!--<Nullable>enable</Nullable>-->`

Probably also related to the fact that the client project, which was the startup project for EF scaffolding didn't have this line, and the class library project did.

In my case the column in the database was a nullable varchar, but project compiled with NRT requires the string property of the model to also be declared as nullable, even though it's a reference type.